# Strange result of sort on Linux

Tags: linux, sorting

I have got strange result of sort on Linux

```
$ uname -a
Linux ... 2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 14 11:36:39 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4
```

Here is file zzz2.

```
   pe/CCC 
   pe_ext/CCC 
   pe/MMM
```

$ sort zzz2

```
   pe/CCC 
   pe_ext/CCC 
   pe/MMM 


Exppected output:
   pe/CCC 
   pe/MMM 
   pe_ext/CCC 



Appendix.

$ od -c zzz2
0000000   p   e   /   C   C   C  \r  \n   p   e   _   e   x   t   /   C
0000020   C   C  \r  \n   p   e   /   M   M   M
0000032
```

Comment: Got any weird unprintable characters at the start of any of the lines?

Comment: Same behaviour happens to me. Linux 3.8.0-29-generic, `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.20`

Comment: I have added output of  od -c zzz2

Answer (score 1):

try to use another locale like

`LC_ALL=C sort filename`

see: https://superuser.com/a/226489